# autowire in returns nullpointer for bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I get the following exception when i try to run my application in tomcat using spring and struts2. Its when struts calls the execute method that it doesnt seem able to access the Autowired OwnerService. Anyone know where the fault might be?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    se.b5.com.database.action.SearchAction.execute(SearchAction.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

My spring.xml looks like this

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="se.b5.com.database"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="se.b5.com.database.model"/>
<!--    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:spring.xml"></property> -->
    <!-- <property name="configLocation" >
    <value>/spring.xml</value>
    </property>  -->

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="ownerService" class="se.b5.com.database.service.OwnerService">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchAction" class="se.b5.com.database.action.SearchAction">  
    </bean>
```

And finaly my SearchActionClass

```
public class SearchAction {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    public void setOwnerService(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }


    public OwnerService getOwnerService() {
        return ownerService;
    }


    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public  void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }


    public String execute() {
        users = ownerService.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println(users.size());
        for(User u : users){
            if(u.getUserName().equals(name)){
                setName(name);
                return "yes";
                }
            }
            for(User u : users){
            if (u.getUserName() != name) { 
                return "no";
                }
            }

        return "no";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is you `SearchAction` class in package `se.b5.com.database`?

Comment: Yes its in se.b5.com.database.action

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify your SearchAction bean to explicitly declare autowiring.

```
<bean id="searchAction" class="se.b5.com.database.action.SearchAction" 
        autowire="byName"/>
```

But really, I'm not sure about this. I've heard it autowires `byType` by default. Also make sure you've added Spring context. This is an example (you may want to use the most up-to-date versions).

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    ...

</beans>
```

Comment: should byName in this case be the class name of the autowired bean?

Comment: I just added the autowire="byName" and it maid no difference, still getting a nullpointer

Comment: `byName` refers to the bean ID. So the variable name `ownerService` in your SearchAction class should correspond to the bean ID `ownerService` in your applicationContext, which it does.

Comment: But I thought it was supposed to autowire by default on the type of the variable (so it would match your instance variable `ownerService` with the one bean of type `OwnerService`). In which case I would make sure you've added Spring context correctly (see second half of the post).